# Postfix block internal communications

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server, zimbra, restrictions

I'd like to know how to block my users to send mail to each other but give them chance to send and receive external mail.

john@localdomain.com <---> julie@localdomain.com REJECT

john@localdomain.com <--->   tom@gmail.com OK

julie@localdomain.com <--->  tom@gmail.com OK

I've already tried to configure access restrictions rules like

```
    /etc/postfix/main.cf:
    smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        ...
        check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/protected_destinations
        ...the usual stuff...

    smtpd_restriction_classes = insiders_only
    insiders_only = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/insiders, reject

/etc/postfix/protected_destinations:
    all@my.domain   insiders_only
    all@my.hostname insiders_only

/etc/postfix/insiders:
    my.domain       OK  matches my.domain and subdomains
    another.domain  OK  matches another.domain and subdomains
```

But that didn't help cause local sender blocked before local recipient checked and local recipient blocked before external one checked.

Answer (score 2):

The configuration above (apparently from [this page](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html)) is used to allow internal-only communication and block the email from outside to internal.

For your case, you need to modify it

```
# /etc/postfix/main.cf:
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    ...
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/protected_destinations
    ...the usual stuff...

smtpd_restriction_classes = reject_insiders
reject_insiders = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/insiders, permit

# /etc/postfix/protected_destinations:
localdomain1.example.com   reject_insiders
localdomain2.example.com   reject_insiders

# /etc/postfix/insiders:
localdomain1.example.com   REJECT local email isn't allowed
localdomain2.example.com   REJECT local email isn't allowed
```

Comment: Actually I did this already and that does now work cause postfix see localdomain of user and block him from sending. I still need user send mail outside. Same picture for recipe - postfix see recipient domain and block so mail won't come from outside...

Comment: Please edit the question and post the `postconf -n` and maillog entry when rejection occurs